# How to reject strange numbers and matching phone numbers in regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been thinking of using this regex for phone numbers: `/(\+\d{1,3})?(\d{9,10})$/`
and I want to exclude these weird number patterns, as example the following regular expressions:

- longer repeat "123123123": `/\b(\d+)\1+\b/`
- repeat number "111111111": `^(\d)\1+$`

I tried with this but i dont have idea of how to combine with the phone number regular expression: `^(\d)(?!\1+$)\d*$`

Comment: This is a really bad idea. Lots of phone numbers have repeating digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to exclude all lines matching your forbidden pattern.

```
^(?!(\d+)\1+$)(\+\d{1,3})?(\d{9,10})$
```

```
^                           // start of line
(?!                         // negative lookahead
    (\d+)\1+$               // matches repeating groups of numbers
)
(\+\d{1,3})?                // optional area code
(\d{9,10})                  // phone number
$                           // end of line
```

https://regex101.com/r/gaA9UN/3

Note that single repeated digits are already covered by the repeating groups pattern, since a single digit is recognized as a group of length one.

### Update

With the updated requirement to also disallow leading repeating groups followed by non-repeating numbers, here's an updated version:

```
^(?!(\d{2,})\1+)(?!(\d+)\2{3,})(\+\d{1,3})?(\d{9,10})$
```

```
^                           // start of line
(?!(\d{3,})\1+)             // disallow three or more leading repeating digits
(?!(\d+)\2{3,})             // disallow 1 or 2 leading digits from
                            //   repeating 4 or more times
(\+\d{1,3})?                // optional area code
(\d{9,10})                  // phone number
$                           // end of line
```

https://regex101.com/r/gaA9UN/4

Comment: yep, but it still matches with `1231236789` and `1111116789` numbers

Comment: Those requirements were not clear from the original description and I'd be surprised if there weren't any phone numbers of the pattern 1231236789. The edit also doesn't specify how many leading digits are considered invalid.